# read only values from specific column in R

Tags: r, excel

I have xlsx document from which I have to read only one column (let's say column 8 for example) Then, I must draw histogram, Q-Q plot and make few more statistic calculations on numbers from this specific column, but I have problem with reading values from column eight.

```
read.xlsx("Dis.xlsx",1)[c(8)]
```

I used this comand to get eight column from my xlsx, but I got next

```
    D6         
1    0.142227420
2    0.457669425
3   -1.384738774
4   -0.902003716
5    0.297755988
6   -0.981665044
7    1.220968465
8   -0.170224221
9    2.071153426
10   0.435652464
11   0.260398690
12   1.152244620
13   0.742319805
14  -1.127973292
15  -0.287556765
```

Why I get line numbers and name of column name? And is there a way to get only values from columns (not the line numbers and column name)
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you need to get comfortable working with data.frames; see [the resources on the R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: What you've got is actually a vector containing only the decimal values you've shown above. The line numbers are shown in R whenever you print a dataframe. Your dataframe currently contains only 1 column ie. D6.

Comment: Did you get this thing working for you?

Answer (score -1):

What you've got is actually a vector containing only the decimal values you've shown above. The line numbers are shown in R whenever you print a dataframe. Your dataframe currently contains only 1 column ie. D6.

To refer to that column/vector you have to use $ operator.

Example:

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("Dis.xlsx",1)[c(8)]
mydata$D6
```

This will give you output of the vector contents.
Hope it helps.